# Symfony 2 version in production

Tags: symfony

I am running the following command on our production server

```
app/console --version
```

and I get the following output

```
Symfony version 2.1.5-DEV - app/dev/debug
```

Is that expected? shouldn't it say "app/prod" or something similar? I am afraid that the configuration on the prod server is actually running the slower dev config

Thanks!

Comment: You should run all console commands with parameter ```--env=prod``` or in your ```~/.bash_profile``` file add line with ```export SYMFONY_ENV=prod```

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's the answer I was looking for. If you want to answer the question I can accept your answer